# Which shell does a gitlab CI job use?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

My .gitlab-ci.yml has the following

```
run python:
  image: python:3.10
  script:
    - |
      cd "src"

      pip install -r ../requirements.txt
      
      ls -l
```

At first I thought it was the entrypoint specified by the image `python:3.10`. However I ran the image locally, I was directly thrown into the Python REPL. It no way runs `cd` .

[image]

So in the script part, which shell is used? sh, bash, or zsh? And is it possible to specify a shell to my liking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it will use bash.
If you want to change that, you can do so on your own runnner instances only.
This is documented here: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/

Answer (score 4):

Here's how it decides:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/blob/d6e1485bc59b1e7f9d47eb3d65d6635b56ed96f7/shells/bash.go#L18-37

```
const BashDetectShellScript = `if [ -x /usr/local/bin/bash ]; then
    exec /usr/local/bin/bash $@
elif [ -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/bash $@
elif [ -x /bin/bash ]; then
    exec /bin/bash $@
elif [ -x /usr/local/bin/sh ]; then
    exec /usr/local/bin/sh $@
elif [ -x /usr/bin/sh ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/sh $@
elif [ -x /bin/sh ]; then
    exec /bin/sh $@
elif [ -x /busybox/sh ]; then
    exec /busybox/sh $@
else
    echo shell not found
    exit 1
fi

`
```